# Attempting to import a weighted graph using networkX

Tags: python, networking, networkx

Im quite new to Python and trying to analyse a basic network using networkX. First of all I'm trying to import my network using an edgelist of the following form:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Where the first column is my source node, the second the target node and the third node represents the weight of the edge. Im using the following code:

```
fh = open('weightedlist.txt',  'r')
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(fh, nodetype=int)
fh.close()
```

As a response, i get the following error:

```
lines = (line.decode(encoding) for line in path)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you assign the variable `path` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_weighted_edgelist.html):

> path (file or string) – File or filename to read. If a file is provided, it must be opened in ‘rb’ mode. Filenames ending in .gz or .bz2 will be uncompressed.